# Why don't onion root tips show mitotic stages?

Tags: botany, mitosis

It was back in the winter that we did the Onion root tip experiment in college. We were able to see wonderful stages but now in this monsoon-autumn transition the root tips hardly show any mitotic stage. Why is it so?